# Scala Style: pattern matching with all branches being wildcards with pattern guard

Tags: scala, coding-style

I'm trying to convince my colleagues that

```
if (totalSize < X) value1
else if (totalSize > Y) value2
else if (totalSize > Z) value3
else func(totalSize)
```

is preferable to

```
totalSize match {
  case _ if totalSize < X => value1
  case _ if totalSize > Y => value2
  case _ if totalSize > Z => value3
  case _ => func(totalSize)
}
```

But I'm having trouble doing that. Counter-argument is that "case-matching is created to eliminate the need for if-else constructs".

Can anyone point me to style guide that has pointers on such usage of pattern matching? I searched but I couldn't find any examples what is considered anti-pattern in such situation.

Comment: While I agree with the beginning of Mario's answer. This question is simple opinion based, being honest both codes look good to me, I would probably go with the `if else`  but the pattern match doesn't looks bad IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

> "case-matching is created to eliminate the need for if-else
>   constructs"

IMHO, pattern matching is not created to eliminate if-else expression. They are both first-class constructs in the language, and it is a value call which one to employ for a particular problem.

Since `totalSize` has no real **structure** to it, I personally do not see much value in pattern matching it in this particular scenario. Pattern matching tour [states](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html#Notes)

> Scala’s pattern matching statement is most useful for matching on
>   algebraic types expressed via case classes.

Here is an example scenario where, IMO, pattern matching is indeed better suited to eliminate an if-else expression

```
if (jf() != null) {
  // proceed with computation
} else {
  // handle error
}

Option(jf()) match {
  case Some(v) => // proceed with computation
  case None =>    // handle error  
}
```

Here is example of `if-else` chaining from Scala [repo](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/7da8ce26ec1f026ec9a8dd295894df49b530e56c/src/library/scala/util/Properties.scala#L212)

```
def compareVersions(s: String, v: String, depth: Int): Int = {
  if (depth >= 3) 0
  else {
    val (sn, srest) = versionOf(s, depth)
    val (vn, vrest) = versionOf(v, depth)
    if (vn < 0) -2
    else if (sn < vn) -1
    else if (sn > vn) 1
    else compareVersions(srest, vrest, depth + 1)
  }
}
```

Comment: gain here is that spacing is more regular. But agree... not big difference.